# Отправка формы при выборе 3 radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html, css, form

Здравствуйте! Есть форма с 9 radiobutton но без кнопки отправки. Они разделены на 3 группы по 3 штуки. Нужно отправить форму когда в каждой группе будет выбран 1 radiobutton. Когда все 3 выбраны нужно мгновенно сделать отправку формы. Натолкните на мысль или возможно кто то знает какой то примерчик.

```html
<form action="#">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <span class="test__h">Оцените </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right smile__box text-right">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <span class="test__h">уровень</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 smile__box pull-right text-right">

                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <span class="test__h">степень</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 smile__box pull-right text-right">

                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile3">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile3">
                <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile3">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form'),
  radio = [].slice.call(form.querySelectorAll('input[name^=smile]'));
radio.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (radio.filter(function(ch) {
      return ch.checked;
    }).length === 3) {
      form.submit();
      // или же, если используете, ajax-ом
    }
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <span class="test__h">Оцените </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right smile__box text-right">
      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile">
      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile">
      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <span class="test__h">уровень</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 smile__box pull-right text-right">

      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile2">
      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile2">
      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <span class="test__h">степень</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 smile__box pull-right text-right">

      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile3">
      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile3">
      <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="smile3">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```